# Java HotSpot(TM) problem after changing java version from 8 to 17

Tags: java, spring-boot, upgrade

during running project after upgrade from java 8 to java 17 the first line is red text:
"Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release."

After that I have got standard start with the logo of spring and next an exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.globema.geoplatform.mapservices.auth.AuthenticationServerApplication
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null"

Does anyone know the way to resolve it?

Comment: Did you rebuild after upgrade to 17?

Comment: Did you look at the stack trace and figure out what it is that causes the crash?

Comment: I made mvn clean install -DskipTests and everything was ok with it, I'll try to check the stack trace

Comment: Now it's ok, I had an old version of Spring..

Answer (score 0):

Java 17 needs Spring Boot 3.x.x

Comment: That is not true, Spring Boot 3.x.x needs Java 17